# USB WiFi adapter antenna capable of broadcasting over long distances?

Tags: wifi, pi-4

I have a large property. And I have a regular wifi network, and my Pi 4, which hosts its own network through a USB WiFi adapter (serving as WLAN1). Is there any way I can rig this to some massive antenna (maybe a long copper tube put upright) so that it will broadcast long distances, rather than just throughout my house? I'm pretty sure that the Pi's USB ports won't be able to provide the power for that, so is there some other way that I can rig this up? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

Hmmmm... The answer to your question is, "No". On a more positive note, there are solutions for the situation you've vaguely described, but they don't involve Raspberry Pi, massive antennas or copper tubing. This is not to say that a solution involving all of these elements cannot be fabricated, but it would be in the style of ["Rube Goldberg"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rube_Goldberg#Cultural_legacy) - perhaps like eating your breakfast cereal with a mop.

In cobbling together a system as you've outlined, it is *necessary* to comply with all of the [physical laws governing rf propogation](https://getyarn.io/yarn-clip/a374aaad-28c6-455f-8127-81d513579a7f), but due to [administrative restrictions on the ISM band - summarized here](https://www.ti.com/lit/an/swra048/swra048.pdf), mastery of the physics is not *sufficient* for a solution.

If you're willing to spend some money, there are [technically robust and legally compliant solutions available](https://unifi-mesh.ui.com/#home). WiFi "mesh networking" is a very viable technology, but implementing it with Raspberry Pis and copper tubing is not a viable approach - I'm sorry to have to break this to you. OTOH, if you're actually looking to implement a "point-to-point" system - perhaps to support a remote WiFi camera setup - this can be done easily enough with directional antennas. Once again however, the laws of physics must guide.

If you care to revise your question with some details (i.e. what are you actually trying to do, and some rough sizing of your "large property") we may be able to help. There are quite a few knowledgeable people here, but all of the "mind readers" I know of are already engaged in politics and social media.